# Как отличить в тексте причастие от прилагательного (на примере "собранный")?

Tags: части-речи, прилагательные, причастия

Можете привести примеры в тексте, где *собранный* выступает как причастие и другой пример, где как прилагательное. Как, в общем случае, отличить два этих случая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Он человек собранный*** - прилагательное,отвечает на вопрос КАКОЙ? и обозначает признак предмета по внешнему виду. Можно заменить синонимами: сосредоточенный, внимательный, аккуратный.

**Собранные цветы поставили в вазу"** - причастие. С цветами что сделали ? - собрали. Есть временной признак.

Подробнее - здесь: [Причастия и отглагольные прилагательные: отличия и правила написания](http://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/prichastija-i-otglagolnye-prilagatelnye-otlichija-i-pravila-napisanija.html)